# How should I draw the (special) is predicate, which is used for arithmetic, in a Prolog search tree?

Tags: prolog

I normally construct my search tree by [following the common convention](http://www.learnprolognow.org/lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse6):

- Place Queries or Goals in need of unification inside node boxes.
- Write down decision points on the edges, where Prolog has assigned an element to a variable.
- Leaf nodes which are fully satisifed will be an empty box, they represent a solution.
- Leaf nodes which can not be satisifed and represent failed attempts will have the unfulfilled goal in their box, to make them even more clear I also follow the convention of marking them by placeing a cross symbol below them.

The above way has the nice side effect that it's easy to see the decision points. But what about creating a search tree for something like:

```
accLen([_|T],A,L)  :-    Anew  is  A+1,  accLen(T,Anew,L).
accLen([],A,A).
```

How should the assignment of Anew be represented in the search tree? It's not a decision point, the code has no other option then assigning it 1 plus the current value of A. Do you still place it on the edge, but underline it or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my view, an `is` predicate is not much different from an explicit unification via `=` or an implicit one via matching of a clause to the input: it causes a variable to be bound. It doesn't leave the interpreter any less choice than `X = 3` does, it's just a bit cleverer about how to retrieve the one possible value that must be assigned.

The only thing that is different is that the `is` cannot succeed until the right hand side is instantiated. If you want to represent this limitation, then you need some special representation, but otherwise I would treat `=` and `is` the same.